# how to send test report playwrite using bitbucket in slack

Tags: bitbucket

I use playwriter for testing. A bitbucket to run the pipeline. I have already written the code that prepares the environment, runs the tests, and saves the test results in artifacts.
But I can't send a report from artifacts to slack in any way.
Everything is fine with the webhook settings. I managed to send a simple report in which there is information about whether the tests pass or not. But here it was not possible to send a report that is stored in artifacts. I would be very grateful for help.

I tried many times to do this, I could not find the correct path to the artifact.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.